# Angular mat-slide-toggle and numeric input

Tags: angular

I have the following Angular code :

```
        <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="device_maintenance_mode"
            [(ngModel)]="isChecked">Maintenance Mode : {{isChecked}}
        </mat-slide-toggle>
        <mat-form-field fxFlex class="mat-block">
            <mat-label>Number of Maintenance DAYS</mat-label>
            <input type="number" step="any" matInput
                    formControlName="device_maintenance_days">
            <mat-error *ngIf="editEntityFormGroup.get('attributes').get('device_maintenance_days').hasError('required')">
                Days number is required.
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

What I want to do is :

When the user changes the value of mat-slide-toggle to true, the input control device_maintenance_days
must be enabled and it's value must be set to 0

When the user changes the value of mat-slide-toggle to false, the input control device_maintenance_days
must be disabled and it's value must be set to 0

Can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `mat-slide-toggle`

```
<mat-slide-toggle 
   formControlName="device_maintenance_mode"
   (toggleChange)="toggleChange()"
   [(ngModel)]="isChecked">Maintenance Mode : {{isChecked}}
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Your `input`

```
<input type="number" step="any" matInput formControlName="device_maintenance_days" [disabled]="isChecked">
```

Your `toggleChange()` in your `component.ts`

```
toggleChange() {
  isChecked = !isChecked;
  this.device_maintenance_days.patchValue(0);
}
```

You don't event have to 2-way bind your isChecked in the `mat-slide-toggle`

Your input will be disabled base on your `isCheck` value